# Configure Logstash to create an Elasticsearch document with nested arrays

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I'm indexing my PostgreSQL data for Elasticsearch using the Logstash JDBC Input Plugin.  I have two tables called `REQUEST` and `ASSIGNMENT` listed below.

**How can I use Logstash to index the two tables into one Elasticsearch document of type `REQUEST` with a nested arrays for all child `ASSIGNMENT` records?**

```
Table: REQUEST

REQUEST_ID | POC
---------- | ----------------
1234       | Jon Snow
1256       | Tyrion Lannister


Table: ASSIGNMENT

ASSIGN_ID | REQUEST_ID | STATUS  | CREATED
--------- | ---------- | ------- | ----------
2345      | 1234       | New     | 2017-01-06
2364      | 1234       | Working | 2017-03-12
2399      | 1234       | Working | 2017-05-20
5736      | 1256       | New     | 2017-06-28
```

This is what I want my Elasticsearch document to look like. It is a sample of the `_source` value of the search result:

```
"_source": {
  "request_id": "1234",
  "poc": "Jon Snow",
  "assignments": [
    {
      "assign_id": "2345",
      "status": "New",
      "created": "2017-01-06"
    },
    {
      "assign_id": "2364",
      "status": "Working",
      "created": "2017-03-12"
    },
    {
      "assign_id": "2399",
      "status": "Working",
      "created": "2017-05-20"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The one idea I have is to concatenate all of my `assignment` data into one column in a Postgres view and then use Logstash Grok to manipulate the data into the desired JSON format, but I don't know if that is possible

Comment: I have the same problem. Actually I read the request and create an empty array "assignments". Now i can't put the assignments as multiple object in the array. The last assignment of request override the previous one

Comment: @DanieleLicitra - I gave up on this approach and just ended up having a separate index for Request and Assignment.  I'd still rather nest my data like above, but I needed something that worked.